# Dependencies between changes in different repositories using Gerrit

Tags: git, dependencies, gerrit

I'm using Gerrit with multiple repositories. One of them contains the core of my application and others use this core (or more specific the maven artifacts build from this project).

I'm not using any kind of git submodules.

One of those other repositories contains a reference project, that is used while developing core features. It also contains the UI tests.

My problem is, that I'm not able to reliably link two changes in different repositories to each other. So when I push my core and reference implementation at the same time, the core builds as expected. But the reference implementation uses the last pushed artifact and fails most of the time (or succeeds against a wrong core version, what seems worse than failing).

Currently the only consistent way for me is, pushing the core, wait for the build to succeed and push the reference app afterwards. I also tried using the topic for that, but I use it for multiple other things (Ticket interactions in my issue tracker) and sometimes I don't need a dependent change, because there is no core change.

So my question is: Are there any concepts to accomplish what I described?

Thanks in advance!